# Password encryption using SecureString for plink.exe command

Tags: powershell, password-encryption, plink, securestring

I would like to encrypt a password in PowerShell

I tried this :

In CLI :

```
Read-Host -prompt "Password ?" -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString | out-file "D:\root.pwd"
```

In my script.ps1 :

```
$pwsNAS = Get-Content "D:\root.pwd" | ConvertTo-SecureString
plink.exe root@192.168.x.y -pw $pwdNAS df
```

But it doesn't work...

I tried with credentials, but it doesn't seems to be better...

(My password doesn't have any space or accented character)

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you want to hand over an 'encrypted' password to plink? Isn't plink part of the putty ssh client implementation? Been about 10 years since I last used MS windows, but I think I recall that the `-pw` option accepts a password, not an encrypted password.

Comment: This script for a personal use, will be in differents computers for all my family, I don't want them to know my NAS' password if the open the script.ps1...

PS: I know that the computer and the user has to be the same for the encryption/decryption, I will do the process on each computer/user

I don't know if I do it well.
In fact I want to use 

`plink.exe root@192.168.x.y -pw $pwdNAS df`

in a powershell script without my visible password...

Comment: Sorry, but trying to protect your credentials that way won't work. What you are doing is obfuscation, not encryption.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for this, finally, it is obfuscation that I want to do...

Comment: Obviously it is a wrong approach to ry to protect a password this way. Think about using keys for this purpose instead of passwords. Use a different key for each system/user/curtomer. This way your password does not get compromised. And don't use the `root` accout with remote access, actually you are stongly advised to disable root login via ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work. `plink` expects a (cleartext) password for the `-pw` option, not a `SecureString` object. If you want to avoid cleartext passwords in your scripts: use public key authentication. If you don't want other people to know your password (or key): give them their own account and password/key.

Answer (score 0):

For connecting via ssh you're far better off using a key, generated by [PuttyGen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) or another key generation tool like that.

However, there is a way to convert secure strings into plaintext strings, detailed [here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/09/21/decrypt-secure-strings-in-powershell.aspx)  Be aware that: a) it will only work if the same user account both encrypts and decrypts the secure string, and b) it's not hugely secure.

Answer (score 0):

For decryption, see [PowerShell - Decode System.Security.SecureString to readable password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468389/850848):

```
$securePass = Get-Content C:\encrypted_password1.txt
$pass = $securePass | ConvertTo-SecureString

$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($pass)
$decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
plink ... -pw $decrypted
```

---

*Though as suggested by the other answers, you better use public key authentication.*