# Use encrypted password for Plink/PuTTY

Tags: powershell, encryption, putty, ssh-keys, plink

I would like to encrypt a password in PowerShell and use it with `plink` and `putty`.

Yes, I know that it expects only cleartext password ([Password encryption using SecureString for plink.exe command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14822083/)).

No, I will not use generated keys because we don't support it.

My questions:

1. Any suggestions how can I use encrypted password for `-pw` flag in `putty` or `plink`
2. Can I generate specific string as key? I mean taking current cleartext password and convert it to a key, then using it as `-i` instead of `-pw`

My `securePass.ps1` code:

```
$password = read-host -prompt "Enter your Password" 
write-host "$password is password" 
$secure = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -force -asPlainText 
$bytes = ConvertFrom-SecureString $secure 
$bytes | out-file C:\encrypted_password1.txt
```

In main:

```
$securePass = Get-Content C:\encrypted_password1.txt
$pass = $securePass | ConvertTo-SecureString
plink -batch -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $pass
putty -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, you cannot use encrypted password (`SecureString`) for PuTTY/Plink.

All you can do is to decrypt the secure string and pass the decrypted plain text password to the PuTTY/Plink.

For for decryption, see [PowerShell - Decode System.Security.SecureString to readable password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7468389/850848):

```
$securePass = Get-Content C:\encrypted_password1.txt
$pass = $securePass | ConvertTo-SecureString

$Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($pass)
$decrypted = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)
plink -batch -ssh $defUser@$srv -pw $decrypted
```

---

PuTTY 0.77 Plink  newly supports [`-pwfile` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pw) that allows more safe way to pass the password via a local text file (while still plain-text).

---

*Your question 2) does not make any sense. You wrote that you cannot use keys. So you cannot use `-i` switch. Let alone use some "generated password" with it.*

Answer (score 1):

```
$Credential = $(Get-Credential)
$user = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Username
$pass = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

is what I use then in the script I use the -pw;
    $ $putty -ssh $server -l $user -pw $pass -m $command

I know that you were saying you did -I instead of -pw however I found this works pretty well that way there is no file with your password stored anywhere.

Answer (score -2):

This was my solution, which runs in a menu loop. works very well. 
I just need "cache" my typed input or (pass prior entered credentials into the dialog, automatically) otherwise every time I have to re-enter credentials.

```
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
     [Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | Out-File AES.key
(get-credential).Password | ConvertFrom-   SecureString -key (get-content AES.key) | set-content "AESPassword.txt"
$password = Get-Content AESPassword.txt |   ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content AES.key)
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($env:userName,$password)
$ServerName = Read-Host -Prompt "What is the server name?"
$Command = ".\plink.exe"
$arg1  =  '-t'
$arg2 = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().username+'@'+$ServerName
$arg3 = '-pw'
$arg4 = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$arg5 = $scriptcmd
#Write-Output $Command $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
& $Command $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5
```

Comment: As with your [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52483733/850848), this **makes no sense**. You prompt a user for a password, encrypt it using "complicated" code, only to decrypt it back and **pass it decrypted to Plink**. Why? - I already wrote you few times: **stop wasting your time**. You cannot pass an encrypted password to Plink. No way.

Comment: Would you mind not commenting on my post? seems your stubborn not able to see other people's point of view. This works for me, If you don't like it... move on :)