# How can I check password complexity?

Tags: powershell, credentials, password-encryption, powershell-5.0, windows-server-2016

I am using PowerShell to create local users. I need to get input from keyboard: Username & Password. To get the password I can use one of the following:

```
$user_details = Get-Credential
```

or

```
$pass = Read-Host -assecureString "Please enter your password"
```

In both cases, I will get encrypted password variable `System.Security.SecureString`. In both cases, when I try to create the user, with

```
New-LocalUser -Name $username -Password $pass
```

I get an error that the password is not complex.

> New-LocalUser : Unable to update the password. The value provided for
>   the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history
>   requirements of the domain."

Since the password is encrypted, (System.Security.SecureString) I have no way to know the complexity of the password. How can I force the user to type a password that complies the complexity rules?

(using unencrypted passwords is not a good solution for me)

Update:
After few answers that were relevant with good solutions, but did not meet my security requirement, I'd like to rephrase:

How can I check password complexity which is already stored in object:
System.Security.SecureString (without decryption)

Comment: `$pass.GetNetworkCredential().Password` voila: plaintext password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Try-Catch is the best way for me to handle this Issue.
I read the password, trying to execute the command
Catch the exception error, and request password again in case of password error

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what TheIncorrigible1 and KoryGill already answered and as you included the error message ***The value provided for the new password does not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain***, you may include a test for the Default password complexity.

If you do a

```
Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy
```

You will get an object like this:

```
ComplexityEnabled           : True
DistinguishedName           : DC=yourdomain,DC=com
LockoutDuration             : 00:30:00
LockoutObservationWindow    : 00:30:00
LockoutThreshold            : 3
MaxPasswordAge              : 42.00:00:00
MinPasswordAge              : 1.00:00:00
MinPasswordLength           : 7
objectClass                 : {domainDNS}
objectGuid                  : 44e3c936-5c8f-40cd-af67-f846c184cc8c
PasswordHistoryCount        : 24
ReversibleEncryptionEnabled : False
```

From this you can check interesting properties like the minimal length for a password in `MinPasswordLength`, after how many **times** a password can be re-used in `PasswordHistoryCount`.
If `ComplexityEnabled` is True, then a password also requires a mix of Uppercase, Lowercase, Digits and Nonalphanumeric characters.

I found an excellent blog about that [here](http://www.checkyourlogs.net/?p=38333) you might want to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy is valid only in domain environment, I use a workgroup (or single) environment.

Comment: @orenk In that case, have a look [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87545-change-minimum-password-length-local-accounts-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 2):

By using if statement in the Powershell script, you can validate the user inputs before moving to the next command. You can get the required password by this:

```html
$Input = Read-Host "Please enter your password. `nPassword must meet complexity requirements: 
`nAt least one upper case English letter [A-Z]`nAt least one lower case English letter [a-z]`nAt least one digit [0-9]`nAt least one special character (!,@,#,%,^,&,$)`nMinimum 7 in length."

if(($input -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($input -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($input -match '\d') -and ($input.length -ge 7) -and ($input -match '!|@|#|%|^|&|$'))
{
    Write-Output "$input is valid password"
}
else
{
    Write-Output "$input is Invalid password"
}
```

Comment: This will get unencrypted password, Which I dont want to use.

Comment: It's just a sample. You can remove the 'write-output' and use the $input value to create the new user. Or you can also use Try-catch method.

Comment: This validates a string against a set rule of requirements, but does not take into consideration which settings are actually in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the password/securestring...

Use the answer from here: [PowerShell - Decode System.Security.SecureString to readable password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468389/powershell-decode-system-security-securestring-to-readable-password)

Then check it against your password complexity as you wish and give the user chances to re-enter it.

Comment: This will unencrypt the password, which is undesired security issue